# How to append a letter(text) to an existing column of numbers at beginning of cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

Can you offer guidance here - I have a column of numbers and need to add a "D" to the beginning of each number in the cell. I do not want the "D" to populate in empty cells. Thank you.Terri

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Superuser. This is not a code writing site, but we like to help. So if you could give us an example of what you already tried, then we could help you by correcting/adjusting your formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Say we have constant data in column **D** like:

[image]

and we run this VBA macro:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range
    Set rng = Columns("D").Cells.SpecialCells(2)

    For Each r In rng
        r.Value = "D" & r.Value
    Next r
End Sub
```

the result:

[image]

The use of `SpecialCells` avoids prepending the *"D"* to empty cells.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a quick-and-dirty solution, I would put a formula in a neighboring column, do a copy/paste-as-value over the original, then delete your formula column.

Formula:
`=IF(D1<>"","D"&D1,"")`

[image]